# Performance of query

Tags: mysql, performance

I have an sql query to get values from 4 tables. In my query takes lot of time. I need to simplify the query 
what i need is i have to display only  50 records. In my table i have 90,000 records. so i deciede to apply batch processing like
first select the 50 records from first table and then check with the 3 other tables.
if the 50 is satisfied i will display that otherwise i have to continue next 50.

But i don't have idea to implement

```
  select file_name, 
         A.id, 
         A.reference, 
         user.username, 
         c.update_date 
    from A_Table A, 
         (select reference 
            from B_Table 
           where code = 'xxx'
           group by reference 
          having count(*) > 1) B, 
         C_Table c, 
         D_Table d
   where A.reference = B.reference
     and A.id = c.id 
     and A.code = 'ICG'
     and c.updated_by = d.user_id  
order by 3 
   limit 20;
```

Comment: show us the explain plan and the indexes on the table

Comment: are o1 and o2 misspells and should be read as A, B respecively?

Comment: In A atble it has 90,000 records. so it takes long time idecided to select first 50 row from table A and compare to others

Comment: @Mihai. yes i need to select 50 from table A first and then use join with 3 others

Comment: do you have any indexes? particulary, on (code, reference) on B_Table?and where from comes user.username?

Answer (score 2):

The query looks fine.

Adding some indexes will help a lot.

Assuming the `id` columns (`A_Table.id` and `C_Table.id`) are already PRIMARY KEY columns, you won't need to index them.

```
ALTER TABLE A_Table
    ADD INDEX (reference),
    ADD INDEX (code);
ALTER TABLE B_Table 
    ADD INDEX (reference),
    ADD INDEX (code, reference);
ALTER TABLE C_Table 
    ADD INDEX (updated_by);
ALTER TABLE D_Table 
    ADD INDEX (user_id);
```

Comment: I would suggest adding also indexes on (code, reference) to both A and B table

Comment: @alko - Good catch, I missed (B.code,B.ref).  Without seeing an explain, I'm not sure I see where (A.code,A.ref) would be used